# how to remove browser cache through the code without logout in grails

Tags: session, grails, groovy

i am facing small problem with search in my application. i.e., the search is performing well at server side but the result is not showing properly at browser side until refreshing the browser.
I don't know exactly the cause for this and i am expecting this may due to session or cache.
how can i over come this.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: hard to say what is going on without any code!is it your search using AJAX?!

Answer (score 1):

Is it IE?  IE tries caching a bit too much by default.  Try adding these Request Headers and see if it helps.

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store");
response.setHeader("Expires","-1");
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the reason for the strange behaviour, try to add a random get parameter to your URL. This way, the browser can't cache the page because it looks like a new one...